# The flag 'api-prefix' for apiserver is not implemented?

Tags: kubernetes

I found the `apiserver` has a flag named `api-prefix`, so I have tried to use it.

I set the flag to `api1` and to keep compatible, I modified the flags of other components like below:

```
kubelet: --api-servers=https://master:6443/api1
kube-proxy: --master=https://master:6443/api1
```

I also tried to modified the flag of `kube-controller-manager` and `kube-scheduler`, but the error below was reported:

```
host must be a URL
```

So I keep the flag of these two components as before.

Now I am wondering about it is because the flag `api-prefix` is not implemented or the way I used them is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the `api-prefix` is completed yet. There are still pending PRs to get it fully operational. This is based on this [comment](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/12951#issuecomment-142961415) to the already merged #12951 PR.

Comment: Thanks, I totally agree with you!